# grep- why must there be word boundaries around back references?

Tags: bash, grep, backreference, word-boundary

I'm just curious why grep matches things in this way.

For example, let's say I'm trying to find a word that occurs twice in a sentence (and not as parts of other words). So I'm trying to find lines like the following :

```
hello everybody hello
```

and not like the following :

```
hello everybody hellopeople
```

Then why does the following grep expression work :

```
grep -E '(\<.*\>).*\<\1\>' file
```

and not the following :

```
grep -E '(\<.*\>).*\1' file
```

I would have thought that the second one would work because the word boundaries (\< and \>) are inside the parentheses for the second match, but it doesn't. It just seems rather confusing that one has to put word boundaries around the back reference, can someone explain why grep matches lines in this way, or maybe elaborate on this idea further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

zero width assertion/zero length match cannot be captured in capture group. `\b or \< \>` are zero length match. It cannot be captured in group. Same as zero width assertion like look behind/ahead.

for example:

```
((?<=#)\w+(?=#)).*\1
```

will match string

```
#hello# everybody hellofoo
```

P.S. you may want to use `\w+` instead of `.*` inside your word boundaries.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `awk` to solve it like this, if you do not get any good `grep` solution.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (a[$i]++) print $i;delete a}'
hello
```

If a word exist more than once in a line, print it.

Comment: Imo the OP question _"...can someone explain why grep matches lines in this way[?]"_ has nothing to do with your answer (ps: no downvotes on my part...)

Comment: Further, your answer assumes that words are separated by whitespace, while in a text words are separated also by punctuation of different sorts.

Comment: @gboffi It will work with both space and tabs, and handle start and end words.  Often looking at something with new eyes helps sort the problem.  Only if its a school work and OP needs `grep` I can see this will not help. Nearly all system that uses `bash` do also have `sed`, `awk` etc.  Sometime there are better solution with using other programs.